# Equality of chemical potential and Normal/Superconductor junction

Tags: thermodynamics, superconductivity

I thought that if I have two $(T,\mu, V)$ system at equilibrium, their chemical potential are equals.

But when I put in contact a normal metal and a superconductor with a tunnel junction, and I apply a voltage between superconductor and normal metal, we will have : $\mu_n-\mu_s=eV$ : the chemical potentials will not be the same.

Why they aren't the same ?

What is the "exact" rule about chemical potentials then (when are they equal).

Also I would like to know why the difference in chemical potential is **exactly** $eV$

Thank you.

Comment: If you apply a voltage between them, they are not in equilibrium.

Comment: Ok but how do we know the difference of chemical potential is exactly $eV$ ?

Comment: Suppose that the normal metal is in contact with the positive terminal of the power supply, in which case the two will quickly reach equlibrium with each other. Similar will happen for the superconductor and the negative terminal. Then, the chemical potential difference will be the same as $e$ times the voltage difference.

Comment: Im not sure to understand why it would be $e$ times the voltage.